Необработанное исключение типа "System.AggregateException" в System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Как обработать это исключение ? мой catch его не ловит)
Использую MySQL.Data
Всё что взаимодействует с MySQL.Data всё находится в try и не упущен никакой await.
Но всё равно, переодически валится приложение из за System.AggregateException.
Необработанное исключение типа "System.AggregateException" в System.Private.CoreLib.dll
One or more errors occurred.

    System.AggregateException
      HResult=0x80131500
      Сообщение = One or more errors occurred. (Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.)
      Источник = System.Private.CoreLib
      Трассировка стека:
       в System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.ExecuteCallbackHandlers(Boolean throwOnFirstException) в /_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/CancellationTokenSource.cs:строка 724
       в System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire(Boolean isThreadPool) в /_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Timer.cs:строка 669
       в System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers() в /_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Timer.cs:строка 331
       в System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() в /_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/ThreadPoolWorkQueue.cs:строка 924
       в System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart() в /_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.cs:строка 77
    
    Внутреннее исключение 1:
    MySqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
    
    Внутреннее исключение 2:
    TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.

В InnerExeptions[0].StackTrace:
   в MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.<>c.<GetTcpStreamAsync>b__8_1()
   в System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.Invoke(Delegate d, Object state, CancellationTokenSource source) в /_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/CancellationTokenSource.cs:строка 977
   в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) в /_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/ExecutionContext.cs:строка 179
--- Конец трассировки стека из предыдущего расположения ---
   в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) в /_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/ExecutionContext.cs:строка 203
   в System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.ExecuteCallbackHandlers(Boolean throwOnFirstException) в /_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/CancellationTokenSource.cs:строка 806


UPD
Свой вариант использования не могу предоставить.
Но не ловится исключение даже в такой простой конструкции:
    while (true) 
    {
        try
        {
            using MySqlConnection? _mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection
            {
                ConnectionString = connectionStringBuilder.ToString()
            };
            await _mySqlConnection.OpenAsync();
        }
        catch (AggregateException ae) 
        {
            foreach (Exception exception in ae.InnerExceptions)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(exception);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }

UPD
Перешёл на MySqlConnector - в коде изменений делать не пришлось, полёт нормальный.

Так где catch то и код, который не ловит? По механике перехвата это исключение не отличается ничем от любого другого.

И всё-равно показывайте ваш код. Вангую наличие async void методов из-за которых вы и не ловите исключения. Но это так, навскидку.

@CrazyElf вот только про async void хотел написать.

@aepot Ну потому что - а как ещё? )  Судя по трейсу, исключение происходит в потоке и не ловится, в то время как автор вопроса говорит, что всё ловит. )  Хотя наверное есть ещё варианты.

AggregateException - наследник Exception, поэтому если вы через try/catch ловите Exception, то оно тоже должно пойматься. Но вот если у вас async void где-то вызван, то вы ничего не поймаете, потому что Task не вернули и вы этот поток больше не контролируете.

@aepot я обновил пост и потестил в простой консрукции и не ловится даже в такой

@CrazyElf обновил

код выглядит нормально, проблема точно не в нём.

@CrazyElf это не блочный using, а более новый синтаксис - using-переменная. Да, код нормальный.

В целом парадигма работы с БД должна быть такая, что открыли коннекшен - обратились к БД - закрыли коннекшен. Держать коннекшен всю дорогу открытым давно уже не нужно, есть пул коннекшенов у самой БД, она моментально вам выдаст свободный коннекшен. А если вы будете держать открытый коннекшен, то вы лично почти ничего не сэкономите, а у БД будет отнят лишний коннекшен из пула.

@CrazyElf вопрос больше про ae - это просто тест - как можно видео добавить чтобы показать как получается ошибка( ?

@PavelMayorov А, точно, я не распознал

В данном случае забыли про catch не вы, а авторы библиотеки MySQL.Data. Судя по стеку, они при истечении тайм-аута пытаются отправить какую-то команду на сервер, чтобы отменить запрос, но у них это не получается, потому что у них истёк тайм-аут.
Классическая ошибка при обработке ошибки. И, так как  это всё происходит при обработке тайм-аута - происходит оно в потоке пула, где вы никак исключение не перехватите.
Могу посоветовать добиться стабильного воспроизведения и отправить баг-репорт авторам, а самому тем временем перейти на нормальную СУБД с качественным драйвером. Например, на Postgres.
UPD:
Вот строка с ошибкой: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/blob/7456bd102cc4193d61b12f82312b3db063aacea1/MySQL.Data/src/common/StreamCreator.cs#L111
using (cancellationToken.Register(() => throw new MySqlException(Resources.Timeout, new TimeoutException())))
    await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(settings.Server, (int)settings.Port).ConfigureAwait(false);

Они не просто упустили исключение из СancellationToken.Register, они его там зачем-то намеренно выкинули! Как будто выкидывание исключения из Register остановит асинхронную операцию.
Автор библиотеки вообще не понимает что делает, и ни разу не проверял свой код. Это не лечится, используйте другую СУБД. В крайнем случае - форкайте библиотеку и переписывайте.

Хорошо бы посмотреть исходники библиотеки, чтобы убедиться, что это так. Пока это ведь просто предположение?

Стабильно не получается( она 1 на 100 раз воспроизводится.
Пол года думал что ошибка у меня( Но попробую сейчас видио хотя бы залить воспроизведения.

@CrazyElf по стектрейсу видно, что  CancellationTokenSource.Invoke вызывает MySql.Data.ЧтоТоТам, и кода приложения между ними нету. Значит, MySql.Data накосячили с обработкой CancellationToken и упустили исключение из делегата, переданного в CancellationToken.Register.

@Xzizz не надо видео, нет ничего хуже чем багрепорт в формате видео. Нужен MCVE и шаги для воспроизведения проблемы.

@CrazyElf нашёл я строку с ошибкой, обратите внимание на обновление в ответе

@PavelMayorov Ого. Да там дичь какая-то, да ))

@PavelMayorov понял, про видео я для местных хотел, а то мне минусы лепят( Получается я не как подобное переловить не могу ? И только искать другую библиотеку))) ?

@PavelMayorov честно, чуть мир перед ногами обвалился, так как думал что try/catch ловит всё...

@Xzizz В однопоточном контексте - да. А когда таски и прочие потоки, то там можно налажать так, что исключения будут выкидываться просто в потоке, который не контролируется вашим кодом никак. Что мы в данном случае и наблюдаем в коде библиотеки. Но вообще вроде была какая-то глобальная ловля ошибок в .NET, если вы прям хотите, то можно на верхнем уровне такие исключения поймать. Другое дело, что непонятно, что с ними делать, если они произошли непонятно где и в каком теперь состоянии то, где это произошло - непонятно. И может ли оно дальше нормально работать, или лучше закрыть лавочку.
